# Numpy array muliplication

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting, vector-multiplication

I have two input arrays and one output array like this:

```
M=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
u=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[2,4,9]])
res=np.zeros((3,))
```

I want to do the following calculation:

```
for i in range(3):
      res[i]=np.matmul(np.matmul(u[0:,i].T,M),u[0:,i])
#res=array([ 231.,  594., 1957.])
```

Can I do it without doing for loop since for loop will take alot of time in larger size matrix

so the goal is to acheive quicker method

Comment: There's no quicker method.  The only way to speed it up would be to parallelize the calculations and create a thread per entry.

Comment: I disagree, if you properly make use of vectorization you can do it a lot quicker!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most intuitive way to do it is probably via [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
res = np.einsum('ki,kl,li->i', u, M, u)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is faster indeed. In case of:
M=[11,11]
u=[11,5590]
for loop: 0.0209 sec
enum: 0.00199 sec

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with `matmul`, you are treating the last dimension of `u` as a 'batch', the one you iterate over in the loop.  If we reshape `u` to be 3d, with that batch dimension first:

```
In [430]: u1 = u.T[:,None,:]; u2 = u.T[:,:,None]

In [431]: u1@M@u2
Out[431]: 
array([[[ 231]],

       [[ 594]],

       [[1957]]])
```

This is (3,1,1), with that batch dimension first, and matrix product in the last 2 dimension.  We can squeeze those out:

```
In [432]: np.squeeze(u1@M@u2)
Out[432]: array([ 231,  594, 1957])
```

The matmul is working with (n,1,3), (3,3), and (n,3,1) to produce (n,1,1), with sum-of-products on the share 3.